# Excel sort with some missing cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

First column is ID code and second column is company's name.

I want to sort by ID first then by company's name.

However, some ID is missing but I still want second column in the order even the ID missing. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Can you give us more detail as to what sort filters you are currently applying and what is actually happening?

Comment: @DavePenn I inserted the image that is what I want to be. Can you see the image?

Comment: This wouldn't be possible just using the sort function.  What is the reason the ID is missing? There is a way that you can fill in the blanks using a "Data" sheet, and then you would be able to sort it using the sort function in Excel.

Comment: please insert your data in an editable format (you can format it e.g. [here](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)) so that we can work on it.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, I generated the table but not editable.  http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables